# How to create form in google app engine using java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How do i create a form in google app engine using java and store the data in the datastore?
 I would be glad if anyone can provide me with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start create form and store the data in the Google App Engine, you can follow [Using DataStore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html).